# Click handler not fired outside foreignObject in firefox

Tags: reactjs, svg, patternfly, foreignobject

I am using DropDownButton and MenuItem elements of patternfly-react v3. DropdownButton translates to  and menuItem translated to

.
This is to create a dropdown, which opens on button click. I also have onClick handler on

I have embedded these elements as foreign object inside svg. When dropdown opens it overflows foreign Object and is visible. Now issue is when i click on

that overflows the foreignObject the click handler handler doesn't get fired if I am using firefox. It works well in safari and chrome. Is this a expected behavior in foreignObject or I am missing something.

Comment: make the foreignObject bigger so it doesn't overflow. Or fix [bug 1071475](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1071475)

Comment: Can't make foreignObject bigger. I use fixed size foreignObject to create graph like view.

Comment: You'll need to download the source code to Firefox and fix the bug then. Happy to review your patch.